# How to take snapshot using VLC Activex Plugin in VB 6

Tags: vb6, vlc

I am using VLC Activex plugin to take snapshot from video stream
But when I call function vlc.video.takeSnapshot, it return **Nothing**
This is the code:

```
Dim pic As IPictureDisp
vlc.playlist.pause                  '--Video is paused
Set pic = vlc.video.takeSnapshot    '--Take snapshot and set it into pic
vlc.playlist.play                   '--Video play again
If pic Is Nothing Then
   Debug.Print "Nothing in pic"
End If
```

Inmediate window display: 'Nothing in pic'
takeSnapshot function defined:

```
Function takeSnapshot() As IPictureDisp
Member of AXVLC.IVLCVideo
take video snapshot and save it into picture object.
```

Anyone help, this function doesn't work anymore, right?

Comment: Have you tried not pausing?  I haven't read the docs, but I'd assume any method called on the video object would be expecting the video to be playing to function correctly.  Also what version of VLC are you working with?

Comment: I'm tried, but it work the same, i'm using vlc.versionInfo, it return "2.1.5 Rincewind"

Answer (score 0):

```
Dim resp As Variant
Dim ls_prev_path As String
Dim ls_temp_path As String
Dim pic As IPictureDisp

ls_prev_path = CurDir
ls_temp_path = App.Path + IIf(Right(App.Path, 1) = "\", "", "\")
ls_temp_path = ls_temp_path + "tmp_snapshot\"

If Dir(ls_temp_path, vbDirectory) <> "" Then
    If Dir(ls_temp_path + "*.bmp") <> "" Then Kill ls_temp_path + "*.bmp"
Else
    MkDir ls_temp_path
End If

ChDir ls_temp_path

vlc1.playlist.pause
Set resp = vlc1.video.takeSnapshot()
vlc1.playlist.play

DoEvents

If Dir(ls_temp_path + "*.*") <> "" Then
    ls_pic_file = ls_temp_path + Dir(ls_temp_path + "*.*")
    Set pic = LoadPicture(ls_pic_file)
End If

ChDir ls_prev_path
```